# Hashage invalide

Tags: transactions

Après une demande de retrait de btc sur mon adresse de portefeuille
L adresse de hashage n'est pas valide.
Je n'ai pas reçu les btc.
Que se passe t' il quand le hash n'est pas valide?

Google translation:

> After btc withdrawal request to my wallet address The hash address is invalid. I did not receive the btc. What happens when the hash is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Some older maintained Bitcoin software may not know about newer address types. For example addresses starting with bc1.

In that case the old software won't be able to create a transaction paying to that address and the money will stay where it was.

Addresses contain a checksum, if there is a small mistake when copying the address, the checksum will not be valid and software will not attempt to create a transaction paying to a mistyped or miscopied address.